# In the Cursed Child, who was Minister for Magic in the alternate reality where Ron is married to Padma Patil?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

In the first Act, Albus and Scorpius interfere in the First Task and because of that, they go to an alternate timeline where Ron is married to Padma Patil and Hermione isn't Minister for Magic, but instead the Hogwarts DADA Professor.

So was the Minister still Kingsley Shacklebolt or someone else?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the minister would be Kingsley, because he was a temporary minister, and there was obviously elections a short while later, since in the story Hermione is elected, so it was probably some other witch or wizard that didn't have Hermione as competition.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question wasn't "who *isn't* the minister," so this isn't a great answer; can you point to any hints as to who _might_ be the minister instead?  More evidence is better, but it doesn't have to be a definitive answer.

Comment: This is guessing, but I feel like JKR would say it's Arthur Weasley

Comment: We don't have any way to know who it was

Comment: Anyone want to ask J.K.Rowling this :)